# Is there a way to query all JobIds or BatchIds from the Bulk Data Load Jobs?

Tags: query, bulk-api, jobs

I've been writing a program that utilizes the Async API to create bulk data load jobs.  I've run into issue with some jobs being left open, after completion, due to Salesforce closing the connection during times of trouble on the servers (particularly NA11/NA15, as of late).  As a result, there are myriad open jobs, just sitting in my Bulk Data section, and I was wondering if there was a way to query all of their IDs, so as to close them, in one fell swoop.  Any help is appreciated, and thank you for your time!

Regards,
Robby

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can query the **Status** field on the **AsyncApexJob** SObject but I'm not sure  it supports DML operation
But you could use instead : **System.abortJob(JobId);**